# Created two buttons but only able to center one

Tags: c#, console-application

i've searched stack overflow but un able to get the exact answer..

i'm doing a school assignment in which i've created two buttons using C# console application not windows form application..now i want to center both of them i'm able to center one of them but not both

this is how i centered my first button but how i can center both of them ?

```
Button btn_1 = new Button();
btn_1.Parent = this;
btn_1.Location = new Point(
    (ClientSize.Width - btn_1.Width) / 2,
    (ClientSize.Height - btn_1.Height) / 2
);
btn_1.Text = "some text";
```

in this way i can center only one button how to center both of them... if i use the same code then they will overlap but how to make both of them appear exactly in center

Comment: can you post the code for the second button?

Comment: is the same code with a different button name

Comment: yes i know... that's why i'm saying that in this way i can center only one button how to center both of them... if i use the same code then they will overlap but how to make both of them appear exactly in center

Comment: did you specify the X and Y position? where are the buttons? how are they ordered? above each other? beside each other?

Comment: i'm asking how to order them , i did'nt ordered them i just made two button.. just tell me that how to make them appear in center.
you know better that which things to specify or not :(

Comment: no one is properly guiding how to center.. everyone interested in down voting the question :(

Comment: I am trying here to understand your current state of the problem. "i'm asking how to order them " please have a look at you post, you are NOT asking this. Wichi technology are you using for displaying the buttons Windows Forms ASP, WPF.. ?

Comment: i'm doing a school assignment . where i have to create two buttons using the C# console application not the windows form app. ok  ? 
and then i need to center both of these button in the exact center of the form

Comment: Are you trying to centre the two buttons next to each other, or one above the other? Either way, if explicitly setting the location, for each button you need to factor in the size of the other.

Comment: i need one above the other and both in center of form :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Layout is above each other, then you can take the first `Button` as reference. Specify the Y-coordinate of the second `Button` as the (Y-Position + the height) of `Button` 1:

```
Button btn_1 = new Button();
btn_1.Parent = this;
btn_1.Location = new Point(
    (ClientSize.Width - btn_1.Width) / 2,
    (ClientSize.Height - btn_1.Height) / 2
);
btn_1.Text = "some text";

this.Controls.Add(btn_1);

Button btn_2 = new Button();
btn_2.Parent = this;

// here use the coordinates of the first button
btn_2.Location = new Point(btn_1.Location.X,
    btn_1.Location.Y + btn_1.Height  // position it below the first button
    );

btn_2.Text = "2";

this.Controls.Add(btn_2);
```

This code will place the second button below the first.

**EDIT:**

If you want both buttons also centred on the Y-Axis you need to move the first button 1 button-height unit upwards like this:

```
btn_1.Location = new Point(
    (ClientSize.Width - btn_1.Width) / 2,
    (ClientSize.Height - btn_1.Height * 2) / 2 // subtract 2 * the height!
);
```

Subtract 2 * the height because you have 2 buttons

Comment: Thankyou Thankyou Thankyou :)

Comment: so they both are in center or btn1 is in center and other is bellow that ?

Comment: @AmmarAhmed the second one is just below. I edited my answer to make them both in the center also in the Y-dimension

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has an accepted answer. But I will propose a (i think that) easier way to centre the 2 buttons. What i would do is use a panel, put the buttons inside,and just centre the panel, something like this:

```
Panel p1 = new Panel();
p1.Size = new Size(0, 0);
p1.AutoSize = true;
Button b1 = new Button();
b1.AutoSize = true;
b1.Text = "Some text";
Button b2 = new Button();
b2.AutoSize = true;

b2.Text = "Some other text";

p1.Controls.Add(b1);
p1.Controls.Add(b2);
b2.Location = new Point(b1.Left, b1.Top+b1.Height);


this.Controls.Add(p1);
p1.Location = new Point((ClientSize.Width - p1.Width) / 2,
                       (ClientSize.Height - p1.Height) / 2);
```